# How to get a report of deleted records list by a user in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, query

I just wanted to get a report in salesforce on Account deleted records by a specific user.

Did anyone have idea kindly please help

Thanks,
Ram Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this in anonymous console.

````
System.debug([select id, LastModifiedBy.name from lead where IsDeleted=TRUE ALL ROWS ]);```
````

Comment: how does this tell you _which user_ deleted the records?

Comment: ha, you are right i missed that in the question. i updated my answer